# Select Repeated Largest Number From Selection with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code :

```
Sub Largest()

Dim strData As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim vValue As Variant
Dim rngCol As Range
Dim lngRow As Long

Dim rngAdd As Range

'Find desired range in which to find the largest value
Dim selectionRange As Variant

selectionRange = Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                        RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Set rng = Range(selectionRange)

'Determines largest value in range
vValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

For Each rngCol In rng.Columns
    'Determines in case the largest value exists in a particular column
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngCol, vValue) > 0 Then
        'Returns row number of the largest value, in the column which has the same
        lngRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(vValue, rngCol, 0)

        'Returns cell address of the largest value
        Set rngAdd = rngCol.Cells(lngRow, 1)

        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In rng
            If (cel.Value = vValue) Then
                cel.Select
            End If
        Next cel
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This is my Selection :

[image]

There are two largest numbers (repeated). This code loops through both the largest value, i.e. 111, but selects only the last looped cell of the largest number, which is `D8`.

How can I select both the cells? I can highlight the cells with colors since it loops through all of the largest numbers when repeated. But I dont want to highlight them with color. I only want to select them, like pressing `ctrl` button and selecting `C6` and `D8`.
Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputRange As Range
    Set inputRange = Selection

    Dim largestNumber As Double
    largestNumber = WorksheetFunction.Max(inputRange)

    Dim myUnion As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In inputRange
        If myCell = largestNumber Then
            If Not myUnion Is Nothing Then
                Set myUnion = Union(myUnion, myCell)
            Else
                Set myUnion = myCell
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

    myUnion.Select

End Sub
```

`Union()` makes a range of cells. Thus, you only need to select the variable, which is created through `Union()`. The tricky part with `Union()` is the way you add to it - you have 2 cases:

```
If Not myUnion Is Nothing Then
    Set myUnion = Union(myUnion, myCell)
Else
    Set myUnion = myCell
End If
```

[Application.Union MSDN](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel)

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @AmanDevrath - the other answer is probably better and easier to be achieved.

Comment: Lovely code @Vityata :). Allthough you are completely right, what if this is done with .findnext? Would it be quicker on a larger set of data? Just for fun, I made a comparison and .Findnext should beat the loop through cells (ill add it in an answer)

Comment: @JvdV - thanks. In general, if one really has time & lust, I guess the fastest would be to parse the range into an Array, search in the Array and remember the coordinates. Then select them.

Comment: @Vityata the other code is working fine. I don't know which to mark as answer. Tell me, will you ?

Answer (score 3):

Credits to @Vitaya. I took his anwer and made it into a .findnext sub

```
Option Explicit

Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim myUnion As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim largestNumber As Long

Public Sub TestMe1()

    Set inputRange = Selection
    largestNumber = WorksheetFunction.Max(inputRange)

    With inputRange
        Set c = .Find(largestNumber, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                If Not myUnion Is Nothing Then
                    Set myUnion = Union(myUnion, c)
                Else
                    Set myUnion = c
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

    myUnion.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Cool! :) Without the `GoTo` it looks even better.

Comment: Working Perfectly fine. I'll research about .FindNext and also will try to understand this code you posted, since I dont know nothing about it. Thankyou for your effort. I don't which one should be marked as answer. Tell me plz. ;)

Answer (score 1):

On the question, one may read this - *like pressing ctrl button and selecting C6 and D8.*

This is quite helpful, because Excel possesses the wonderful "Macro-Recorder" (no irony here). Thus, a macro recording is really a good idea here:

It produces `Range("C6,D8").Select`

Now, if somehow the `C6,D8` can be passed to a range and the range is selected, then the job is already done. Thus, on each iteration, we add the address of the cell and a comma after. The only problem seems to be the comma, because `C6,D8,` would not be valid. This is achieved with some slicing:

```
toBeSelected = Left(toBeSelected, Len(toBeSelected) - 1)
```

This is the whole code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputRange As Range
    Set inputRange = Selection

    Dim largestNumber As Double
    largestNumber = WorksheetFunction.Max(inputRange)

    Dim toBeSelected As String
    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In inputRange
        If myCell = largestNumber Then
            toBeSelected = toBeSelected & myCell.Address & ","
        End If
    Next myCell

    toBeSelected = Left(toBeSelected, Len(toBeSelected) - 1)
    Range(toBeSelected).Select

End Sub
```